# Color wheel vector xml drawable in Android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, vector, drawable

I have a problem with color wheel i want something like this [LINK to Image wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTFC3.jpg)  but only what i have is this [LINK to Image current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ30D.png) and beetwen yellow and green you
see break. Any idea to solve this ? Or other solution to do this ?
code below :

```
  <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">

          <gradient
              android:type="sweep"
              android:centerX="6"
              android:centerY="6.4"
              >

            <item
                android:color="#17DE2B"
                android:offset="0.114"
                />

            <item
                android:color="#3D5FD9"
                android:offset="0.376"
                />

            <item
                android:color="#FE00F4"
                android:offset="0.629"
                />

            <item
                android:color="#E9D100"
                android:offset="0.879"
                />

          </gradient>

        </aapt:attr>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
I trying and add next item in gradient like this:

```
<aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient
                android:centerX="6"
                android:centerY="6"
                android:type="sweep">

                <item
                    android:color="#17DE2B"
                    android:offset="0.114" />

                <item
                    android:color="#3D5FD9"
                    android:offset="0.376" />

                <item
                    android:color="#FE00F4"
                    android:offset="0.629" />

                <item
                    android:color="#E9D100"
                    android:offset="0.879" />

                <item
                    android:color="#17DE2B"
                    android:offset="1" />
            </gradient>
        </aapt:attr>
```